# wordpress custom mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

In wordpress How can we fetch records in specific order within meta field value for eg I need to fetch all records where zip_code(meta key name) is all fields with 60007 first than all 60143 than 60191

**Table drrr_posts**

```
Id  | post_name |   content
2
3
4
22
32
43
```

**Table drrr_postmeta**

```
id | meta_key   | meta_value  |     post_id
1  |  zip_code  | 60143       |    2
2  |  zip_code  | 60007       |    3
3  |  zip_code  | 60191       |    4
4  |  zip_code  | 60143       |    22
5  |  zip_code  | 60007       |    32
6  |  zip_code  | 60143       |    43
```

I think issue is I am passing **ORDER BY FIELD( drrr_postmeta.meta_value** not zip_code which is meta_key
In mysql I can easily pass the values in ORDERBY like

```
ORDER BY FIELD(name, 'B', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'C')
```

here is what I have now
**My Query is**

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS drrr_posts.ID
FROM drrr_posts
INNER JOIN drrr_term_relationships ON ( drrr_posts.ID = drrr_term_relationships.object_id )
INNER JOIN drrr_postmeta ON ( drrr_posts.ID = drrr_postmeta.post_id )
INNER JOIN drrr_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( drrr_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )
WHERE 1 =1
AND drrr_posts.ID NOT
IN ( 91, 89, 87, 66 )
AND (
drrr_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
IN ( 11 )
)
AND drrr_posts.post_type = 'doctors'
AND (
(
drrr_posts.post_status = 'publish'
)
)
AND (
drrr_postmeta.meta_key = 'zip_code'
AND (
mt1.meta_key = 'zip_code'
AND CAST( mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED )
IN (
'60007', '60143', '60191', '60005', '60106', '60157', '60173', '60008', '60056', '60172'
)
)
)
GROUP BY drrr_posts.ID
ORDER BY FIELD( drrr_postmeta.meta_value, '60007', '60143', '60191', '60005', '60106', '60157', '60173', '60008', '60056', '60172' )
LIMIT 0 , 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order your results by meta_key by adding one more conditional order by ,also your group by statement doesn't make any  sense in absence of aggregate function ,for now you can do this

```
ORDER BY 
drrr_postmeta.meta_key ='zip_code' desc,
FIELD( drrr_postmeta.meta_value, '60007', '60143', '60191', '60005', '60106', '60157', '60173', '60008', '60056', '60172' )
```

Using `drrr_postmeta.meta_key ='zip_code'` will result as a boolean and returns true if both matches so it will order results first by zip_code matching meta_key and then you `field()` function will order results accordingly

Comment: @June try now my bad missed comma after desc

Comment: Result is still the same is there any means I can send you the database tables?

Comment: What I get is http://puu.sh/bhh2m/c6b423f9fc.png I wan to fetch all 60007 first than all 60143 and so on, it seems to be only looking in first 8 results?

Comment: @June yes you can provide your tables with sample data @ [*sql fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @June in your [*image*](http://puu.sh/bhh2m/c6b423f9fc.png) 60007 is at first place you are getting right results